# Can I consider Quantum Logic as Three-valued Logic?

Tags: logic, quantum-computation

As I understood, *Quantum Logic* is the logic system in which the truth values can be either **(True)**, **(False)** or **(both True and False)**.

Can I consider this system as one of the *Three-valued Logic* systems?

If so, which *logic systems* (such as Kleene system, Łukasiewicz system, etc.) would be appropriated?